# race conditions with php sessions and ajax request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session-variables, laravel-5

I have a shopping cart I built myself that uses session variables to maintain the state of cart across requests. I have an increment and decrement button that allows users to increase or decrease the quantity of a product in their cart. this happens via an Ajax request. The cart class operates by restoring the cart out of the session when constructed, and saving the cart back to the session when destructed.

```
<?php

class Cart {

    /**
     * constructor
     */
    public function __construct(){

        //restore cart
        $this->restore();
    }

    /**
     * destructor
     */
    public function __destruct(){

        //save cart
        $this->save();
    }

    /**
     * restore
     */
    public function restore(){

        //retrieve session info
        if(Session::has('cart')){

            //get cart
            $session = Session::get('cart');

            //assign session info
            $this->data = ($session['data']);
            $this->rates = $session['rates'];
            $this->lines = $session['lines'];
        }
    }

    /**
     * save
     */
    public function save(){
        Session::put('cart', $this->forSession());
    }
```

the problem I'm running into is a race condition with multiple Ajax requests. the user can hit the button many times, sending multiple Ajax requests. each request is therefore pulling the current state of the session, doing the operation, and then saving it. the problem is the previous transaction is not necessarily completed and saved when it `restore`s the cart. my first fix was to make any subsequent Ajax requests cancel the previous one, to both cut down on unnecessary (immediately overwritten) requests, and also to help avoid this race condition. while it seemed to help, it still acts quirky. So my next thought was to attack it at the source, namely the cart class itself. my idea was to implement some type of 'locking' to prevent the cart from being accessed until a previous operation was completed. The idea looked something like this.

```
<?php

/**
 * is cart locked
 */
public function isCartLocked(){

    if(Session::get('cartLock') === 1){
        sleep(1);
        $this->isCartLocked();
    }
}

public function restore(){

    Session::put('cartLock', 0);
    //check if cart is locked
    $this->isCartLocked();

    //lock cart
    Session::put('cartLock', 1);

    ...
}

public function save(){

    //unlock the cart
    Session::put('cartLock', 0);

    ...
}
```

now the first question is, SHOULD I be doing something like this, with the locking? And then, if so, is this a decent way to handle it?

After my first attempt at it, the problem I seem to be running into is the destructor is not necessarily called all the time, which is causing my cart to stay locked, and eventually causing a timeout error.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

I'd think that you would actually want to debounce the function call to the AJAX request so that you're not concerning yourself with locking/unlocking or cancelling previous requests - just make one once you're relatively sure they're done adjusting the quantity.

I would recommend [this jQuery plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/) for throttling or debouncing JavaScript function calls (though jQuery actually isn't required to use this, it's just accessible through the jQuery namespace if available), assuming that's how you're making your AJAX request.

Comment: debouncing looks like a good fix to this problem. while it is definitely something I will look into implementing, I would also really prefer a server side solution as well, so I attack the problem at the source, and don't rely on a client side solution to prevent this from happening.

Answer (score 0):

I would have to say that if you are running into race conditions then you have some issues in regards to your application design, and these sorts of issues may haunt your application for a while since concurrent accesses of the session will be smashing your session store relatively frequently

The easiest way to do something like this in my opinion would be with a database table and instead of updating a field one would be adding a row for each user event ( so a increment action would insert , , , 1. And a decrement would insert a row of -1 )

This way you can simply do a sum operation to tally your counts, and when the users checkout process is complete you can clear up the entire order in the cart table .

Comment: while i'm sure that could work, i personally don't believe a database based solution is appropriate for something as temporary as a cart. depending on how many entries were created, and how big the user base is, all of these DB transactions could get very expensive.  thank you for the suggestion but I would prefer a session based solution.

Comment: Depending on your session store you may be doing db writes anyway . Aalthough if you are getting to the type of scale that database access becomes a bottleneck the performance impact of all the direct disk io from writing to the session store will also be significantly detrimental, I have found from a practical standpoint a  scratch table can be quite efficient, in the event of huge scales you could look at installing a local scratch database on each load balanced node anyway.

Comment: currently I'm using native sessions, although with Laravel, that can be easily switched to db or cookies. interesting thoughts. i'm hoping someone can chime in with a session based solution, as well

Comment: The issue that you will come across with sessions is really the fact that when you call session_start all values are read into ram, and then when you call session_write then everything which is in ram is persisted, causing a architectural issue which leads to your race condition. Php unfortunately does not support any form of locking mechanism. If you simply switch your sessions to a db storage mechanism this will not solve the issue .